# How can I recognize text inside another shape in an image using Tesseract

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

[image: Image in grayscale]
I am trying to recognize the text "25" inside the hexagon. My code can recognize text if it is above or below the hexagon, but not when inside the hexagon. Any pointers? Also, I am trying to get the coordinates of the text. 
One option would be to extract the hexagon (using opencv contour) into another image and then use tesseract. But is there a simpler solution that I can use?

Here is the code snippet to recognize if the text is outside the shape (the program takes image file name as an arg and prints out the text that it recognizes.)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter  
import sys  
import pytesseract  
import cv2

load image filename = sys.argv[1]

img = Image.open(filename) 
img = img.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN) 
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img) 
img = enhancer.enhance(10) 
img = img.convert('1') 
img.save('temp.jpg')

im = cv2.imread('temp.jpg',cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)  
im = cv2.blur(im,(4,4))
_, im = cv2.threshold(im, 200 , 200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

#This is just to see what has happened, has no meaning! 
cv2.imshow('gray', im)  
cv2.waitKey(0)  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#Actual Text recognition 
cv2.imwrite('temp2.jpg', im)  
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('temp2.jpg'))  
print(text)
```

Comment: How are you recognizing it above and below the hexagon?

Comment: @Sruti as mentioned above let us know how you are able to perform OCR above and below the hexagon?

Comment: Added the program to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The digit is in the center of the shape, you can easily get by playing with the coordinates.

For instance:

- get from `height/2-30` to `height/2+30` and
- get from `width/2-30` to `width/2+30`

Then apply threshold

|  | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Part of the image | [image] |
| Threshold | [image] |
| Pytesseract | 25 |

Sometimes when you can't get the desired result, you need to apply [pre-processing](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('769b9.jpg')
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = gry[int(h/2)-30:int(h/2)+30, int(w/2)-30:int(w/2)+30]
thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr)
print(txt)
cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```